# CLI to check thread count in WildFly domain mode

Tags: wildfly

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
            <worker name="default" io-threads="100" task-max-threads="200"/>
            <buffer-pool name="default"/>
</subsystem>
```

I have set IO threads like this in WildFly-8.2 domain mode. What is the exact command to view this thread count during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you added this config to wildfly domain mode, I presume that you have modified a certain profile. The cli commands in domain mode are the same as in standalone operation, they just need to be prefixed with `/profile=<NAME_OF_YOUR_PROFILE>`. So if you have updated the full-ha profile for example you can use the following `/profile=full-ha/subsystem=io/worker=default:read-resource`

Comment: It's showing only the values set in configuration file. Is there any way to get how many thread are currently used? eg: io-threads="100" configured, how may already used/available at runtime?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way ho to check the runtime stats of IO worker pool. You have access to total thread stats of specific instance or information about thread pools- e.g. slsb thread pool. In domain mode, you have to query this information on a particular instance, because each can have a different load and different pool states. To query total thread stats for given server you can use: `/host=<YOUR_HOST>/server=<YOUR_SERVER_INSTANCE>/core-service=platform-mbean/type=threading:read-resource` There you see for example:   "thread-count" => 237,  "peak-thread-count" => 301,